# How to check if textbox is disabled in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to confirm and verify a textbox is disabled and not enabled

I tried below asserts, but it doesn't do the work

```
Assert.IsFalse(formPage.Name.Enabled);
Assert.AreEquals(null, formPage.Name.GetAttribute("value"));
```

Below is the Element for the textbox

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <lable class="placeholder">Name</label> 
    <input disabled class="form-control first-name-input-large" value> ==$0
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In selenium there is the .Enabled(), you could use that to check if it's enabled or not.

```
driver.FindElement(by).Enabled
```

it only works for input methods, if you want to check something that isn't a input method you should use GetAttribute("disabled"), that will return a bool value.

you can read more about the method in the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Enabled.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can assert the length of list returned from this command is not 0 i.e. the such element exists:

```cs
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@class='form-control first-name-input-large' and @disabled]"))
```